# shell Command execution Failing when executed from Java

Tags: java, command-line, sybase

When I execute the below command on command line, it shows all the stored procedures and tables in the sybase DB.

```
printf 'sp_help\ngo\n' | isql -Uxx -Pxxxx -Dxxxxx
```

But when I do the same thing in java. This does not return any result.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code below:

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   String cmd = "printf "+"\'sp_help\ngo\n\'"+"| isql -Uxx -Pxxxx -Dxxxxx" ;
   try{ 
          Process p;
          p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
          p.waitFor();
          String line; 
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

           while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
           System.out.println("Row is :" + line);
   } catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Exception Caught : " + e);
       }

  }

}
```

**EDIT**
I executed it as below suggested by Darkdust but still it doesnt work.

```
try{
          Process p;
          p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh -c \'printf \"sp_help\ngo\n\" | isql -Uxx -Pxxxxx -Dxxxxxx\'");
          p.waitFor();
          String line;
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

           while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
           System.out.println("Row is :" + line);
  }
 }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.out.println("Exception Caught : " + e);
       }
```

But the command :

```
sh -c 'printf "sp_help\ngo\n" | isql -Usa -Psybase11 -Dcnadb'
```

Works on command line.

I also tried with :

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","-c","\'printf \"sp_help\ngo\n\"","|isql -Uxx -Pxxxxx -Dxxxxx\'"});
```

But with no sucess.

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind:

- Incomplete PATH environment variable (thus `isql` can't be found).
- If it's a command you provide, instead of messing with PATH you might want to make sure your are you in the correct working directory and call `./isql` instead.
- Since you're using a pipe, you should let a shell execute this as in `sh -c "foo | bar"`. Otherwise the `| isql ...` part is passed as argument to `printf` as well.

Comment: isql PATH is available. As i said that the command runs as expected from command line. Why the same is not running as expected in java? And i think the whole `cmd` will be executed on command line and output will be retrieved into java

Comment: See my last point. Java might run "printf" and pass _everything_ as arguments to "printf", even the pipe symbol and everything afterwards. You need to run a shell and let that run your command, as in `sh -c "printf 'sp_help\ngo\n' | isql -Uxx -Pxxxx -Dxxxxx"`. You probably want to use the `exec` variant with an `String[]` argument: IIRC, it should be `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", cmd});` (my Java is rusty).

Comment: OK.. I got your point. But the problem now i am facing is `sh -c "printf "sp_help\ngo\n" | isql -Uxx -Pxxx -Dxxxxx"` is not working on the command line itself if i add `sh -c` as prefix to the command.It gives me an error Usage: printf format [argument...]

Comment: No, I do not mean to write a bash script. On the shell, you would need to enter `sh -c 'printf "sp_help\ngo\n" | isql -Uxx -Pxxx -Dxxxxx'` (or use `"` and escape them inside with `\"`). Most likely all you need to do is replace your `p = ...` line with `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh", "-c", cmd});` (in this case no extra `"` escaping is necessary). Have you tried that?

Comment: Did you happen to fix the issue?

Comment: This is a very late answer, sorry, but the call should be: `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"sh","-c","printf \"sp_help\ngo\n\" | isql -Uxx -Pxxxxx -Dxxxxx"});` The `'` should be removed (your shell is doing that for you when you type that at the command prompt which is why it worked), the whole argument `printf \"sp_help\ngo\n\" | isql -Uxx -Pxxxxx -Dxxxxx` must be one string.